# Static noise on laptop screen after update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde

I've just updated my laptop running KDE Neon with the help of `pkcon refresh && pkcon update`. After restarting my laptop screen shows a weird static noise on the screen which I cannot remove. You can see this in the following video I made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-oZB6sCptU
Weirdly enough, my external screens are working just fine.

neofetch shows the following:
[image: neofetch]

display manager: ssdm

I really have no clue what might be causing this and how to solve it. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Please let me know if I need to provide more info!

Answer (score 0):

This exactly happened to me today after I booted, same kind of static as well. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, it happened after updating, and I have AMD CPU and Nvidia GPU

What fixed it for me was updating to version 21.04.

Comment: I am running KDE and am already on the latest version. I just did a fresh install of KDE neon. It works fine until I do pkcon update. I guess there is some issue in the latest upgrade which causes AMD devices to behave like this?

Comment: I wouldn't know @JeroenBeljaars

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Kubuntu 20.04.

It seems the problem is caused by version 5.13 of the kernel. Downgrading to 5.11 fixed that.

Here is the bug report about this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958591.